# Is CVE-2024-20666 Bitlocker vulnerability mitigated by disabling Windows RE or removing the recovery parition?

Tags: windows, bitlocker, vulnerability-management

Taking Microsoft's [page on CVE-2024-20666](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2024-20666) at face value, that Bitlocker vulnerability is darn serious in an "evil maid" attack:

> A successful attacker could bypass the BitLocker Device Encryption feature on the system storage device.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Attack Vector | Physical. The attack requires the attacker to physically touch or manipulate the vulnerable component. |
| Attack Complexity | Low. Specialized access conditions or extenuating circumstances do not exist. An attacker can expect repeatable success against the vulnerable component. |
| Privileges Required | Low. The attacker is authorized with (i.e., requires) privileges that provide basic user capabilities that could normally affect only settings and files owned by a user. Alternatively, an attacker with Low privileges may have the ability to cause an impact only to non-sensitive resources. |
| User Interaction: | None. |
| Confidentiality (impact) | High. |
| Integrity (impact) | High. |
| Report Confidence | Confirmed. |
| Publicly disclosed | No. |
| Remediation Level | Official Fix. |

The official fix is a Windows Recovery Environment update. Unfortunately it fails to install on some machines. Reasons include too small a recovery partition, something with a  [semi-official remedy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5028997-instructions-to-manually-resize-your-partition-to-install-the-winre-update-400faa27-9343-461c-ada9-24c8229763bf). But there are others, like missing `Winre.wim`, and then there are several versions of that, including one updated December 2023. Update: did not yet try that later [near-official remedy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5034957-updating-the-winre-partition-on-deployed-devices-to-address-security-vulnerabilities-in-cve-2024-20666-0190331b-1ca3-42d8-8a55-7fc406910c10).

##### Questions

Are machines where WinRE is disabled (e.g. by `reagentc /disable`) vulnerable?

If yes, are machines where further the recovery partition is deleted and it's space reclaimed vulnerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KB5034441: Windows Recovery Environment update for Windows 10, version 21H2 and 22H2: January 9, 2024](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5034441-windows-recovery-environment-update-for-windows-10-version-21h2-and-22h2-january-9-2024-62c04204-aaa5-4fee-a02a-2fdea17075a8) states

> If your running PC does not have a WinRE recovery partition, you do not need this update.

This seems to imply machines where the recovery partition is deleted and it's space reclaimed are safe. My experience is Windows Update still tries to install KB5034441 and fails with error 0x80070643, which is only annoying.

I have had no problem deleting the recovery partitions on some PCs, using `reagentc /disable`, then in Diskpart selecting the *appropriate* partition and using the `override` switch when deleting the partition; then reclaiming the space using the GUI when that partition is after the main partition. I purposely do not state the complete procedure to avoid responsibility in accidents.